# Absolutely every question I ever ask on Programmers ends up being a bad question and put on hold for off topic

Tags: support, site-recommendation, close-reasons, off-topic, on-hold

Absolutely every question I ever ask on programmers.stackexchange.com ends up being a bad question and put on hold due to being off topic.

Where can I ask my questions without having to constantly defend from negative comments and votes, the question being put on hold, etc?

Not every programming question has a definitive answer, and those whose answers can be a bit more ambiguous or open for interpretation are also very important. Especially when if you are like me, you don't know anybody in real life or on the internet, that could help you. I could search around for forums, but there is not as much activity there as it is here, for me to get timely feedback.

I have no one to ask. And now, apparently, nowhere to ask for help too.

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287516/is-rxjava-something-that-we-need-to-learn-or-is-it-just-a-fad
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222834/i-cant-get-myself-to-sit-down-and-start-coding
- [Absolutely every question I ever ask on Programmers ends up being a bad question and put on hold for off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259116/absolutely-every-question-i-ever-ask-on-programmers-stack-ends-up-being-a-bad?noredirect=1#comment844726_259116)

And there are at least 3 or 4 more questions that I had to delete before my reputation would have hit rock bottom.

Where do I ask these questions?

Comment: You got 8 upvotes **and accepted answer** - this is really not a good example for "bad question"..

Comment: There, even this question where I honestly ask for a clarification gets only downvotes and no normal explanation.

Comment: Well since this is a feature request, most people will downvote because they do not agree with you

Comment: I was told by the system that I needed to use this tag, otherwise I wasnt allowed to submit my question. I dont want a new feature, I just want people to tell me where to ask my questions that have no definite answers

Comment: Actually, you were told by the system that you need to use at least _one of_ "feature-request", "discussion", "support", or "bug".

Comment: Actually my -1 is because it's just a rant without anything towards constructive discussion.

Comment: There is no answer in the proposed question that is supposed to already have an answer

Comment: Did you consider the option that none of your questions are on-topic, either on programmers.se or, given the nature of the questions, nowhere within in the SE network? To answer your question: try http://quora.com

Comment: Thank you!! Now this looks like something that I can rely on. Thank you again. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @J.K. You can rely on Stack, just in a more specific way than a forum-like site where you can ask in any manner and people will "discuss" until you have your answer(s) :)

Comment: *Absolutely every question I ever ask on programmers.stackexchange.com ends up being a bad question and put on hold due to being off topic.* You're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer you based on each of the example questions you provided.

---

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287516/is-rxjava-something-that-we-need-to-learn-or-is-it-just-a-fad

The Stack sites need/want questions which can be directly answered, not discussed or opinions provided.

Your actual question there was "Do you see future in RxJava?".
I do yes, Bob does not, Sally is not sure, Mary things it's a terrible thing and states strongly no....

It's all just going to be opinion, because there is no actual factual answer to determine if there is a future for it.
Sure, one could assess if it's active - is there is a good level of support and if there are updates, etc. But it just isn't a question that can be answered very well on Stack Exchange format.

Consider what is the basis and definition of "is there a future".
Are we talking it will last 6 months? 6 years?
It stays live with 2 updates per year? Or to "have a future" it needs an update each month?

What defines "a future" in this scenario?
No-one knows, or more to the point, we all define this differently, so answers will be "opinion".
Hence the close reason "put on hold as primarily opinion-based".

---

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222834/i-cant-get-myself-to-sit-down-and-start-coding

This question has a lot of positive activity. That's because while the sites have rules, and this is deemed as off-topic, the site also has users who are just people. And people can decide for themselves away from site rules.
In this case, while it was "technically off-topic", the site users felt there was some good content and provided their inputs.

It was given feedback from users (people) because they are human and wanted to show compassion and give you advice, but it is off-topic simply because you asked about "career advice" on a site for "Programming" questions.

It was also off-topic (rightly or wrongly this is how the sites work) because your question would only help you, and Stack is designed to be a resource for many users.
Sure, the person who asked the question gets their question answered, but it's supposed to be useful to many. Hence the "too localised" close reason.

---

- [Absolutely every question I ever ask on Programmers ends up being a bad question and put on hold for off topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259116/absolutely-every-question-i-ever-ask-on-programmers-stack-ends-up-being-a-bad?noredirect=1#comment844726_259116)

This question is on Meta, and Meta questions are a different beast.
Downvotes here on Meta are about more than suggesting a question is just good or bad. On Meta People use votes for "yes", "no", "I agree", "I disagree", "bad question", "not useful", "no research effort", etc. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Your question doesn't really seek valuable input from the community, in that you came here with a bit of a ranty attitude, and rightly or wrongly that is just not welcomed.

Breaking down the reasons:

> Absolutely every question I ever ask on programmers.stackexchange.com
>   ends up being a bad question and put on hold due to being off topic.

You only have 5 questions on Programmers, and 4 of them were "well received" (albeit one of them was closed).
So this is not only a bit ranty, but also a false statement.
You have received good answers on *most* of your questions.

> Where can I ask my questions without having to constantly defend from
>   negative comments and votes, the question being put on hold, etc?

Stack Exchange sites, just ask where it's on-topic, and ask a good question.
See the Help Center for the site you want to ask on, specifically the ""What's on topic here", and "What should I avoid asking" posts.
These vary from site to site and give specific info for the site you are on.

> Not every programming question has a definitive answer

Such questions are simply (99% of the time) off-topic, that's just how it is, it's how Stack is designed.

> and those whose answers can be a bit more ambiguous or open for
>   interpretation are also very important.

I don't disagree that "questions with ambiguous answers are important", they help us, when we need to discuss our scenario a bit more and try to learn, but regardless of how much such questions and answers help you (and me and others) they are simply off-topic here.

> I could search around for forums, but there is not as much activity
>   there as it is here, for me to get timely feedback.

2015 and you cannot find an active forum for tech/coding support?
They are out there!

Perhaps you *have* tried, and that would mean you either haven't tried enough, or are searching with the wrong keywords or looking in the wrong places.

Perhaps jump into a Stack chat room (like Programmers chat, or Stack Overflow chat) and ask what are good tech/programming sites where you can ask techy questions which are a bit off-topic here.
People will help you, if you approach in a friendly manner ;)

---

I agree that Stack is a great resource, and there are a lot of professionals waiting to give you some fantastic advice. But you have to ask in the manner which the site requires.
One of the reasons the sites have great resources is because they don't allow open-ended and opinionated questions.

The lack of the aforementioned provides clear answers to specific questions - which helps everyone.

I suggest you find a good forum or whatever for questions which are not on-topic here at Stack, then when you have a question which would be on-topic here ask it here.

Comment: Thank you for being so good and answering so well.

Answer (score 7):

If you want opinions/perspectives and not a definitive answer, such as for the two questions you linked, you should use *chat* and not a Q/A site.

- "Is something a fad?" <-- completely subjective and opinion based. It's by definition impossible to answer that, since fads come/go.
- "I can't help myself" <--- also impossible to answer conclusively.

Try chat. Seriously, these sorts of questions cannot be answered well in a Q/A site which is why they get closed..

Answer (score 3):

Well let's see why your questions were swiftly closed and maybe downvoted to oblivion as you stated. The first question:

> Do you see future in RxJava?

That is extremely broad and can send people into "war" as their opinions will clash against their "rivals". This is not considered a good question and should be closed without further ado. If you ask a ***specific*** question related to RxJava, then maybe the question can stay and be upvoted and not be closed.

If you still want to ask the question, ask in the appropriate chat room for your site. That is where debate is allowed but is under control by your fellow users. My advice: **Post this in chat**.

The second question was already amazing. 8 upvotes plus an accepted answers with 6 upvotes. Now that's a question. But this part ruined it all:

> PS: Why would someone downvote my question? what wrong or bad have I done? Which rule have I not obeyed?

That is a meta question not needed. Thus this why your question was closed ***after*** you edited the question to add this part. Questions on how the system/site works must be asked on the appropriate meta site or simply observed.

If you hover above the downvote button, it will show you why someone would downvote your question. Whether what you done wrong is simply a user's opinion and if your question stays positive, there is no need to worry. The community can immediately "answer" that part by providing advice (if the question needs improvement), votes, and hopefully answers. If you get good answers, it is more than likely that your question is at least satisfactory. My advice: **Delete that part. Manually remove it or use a rollback.**

And finally you added this question to ummm... this question. There are many reasons why people will downvote your question. Since you used [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), some people will not agree with you and downvote your question, trying not to let the request be applied and vice versa.

Some just don't like the way you wrote the question which confused them thus the downvotes. It isn't clear on what your problem is and sometimes people might think it's just a rant with no constructive discussion available as said by Shadow Wizard. My advice: **Look at highly upvoted questions in your site. See what they have and you don't. Try to learn from them and please use the Help Center to help improve your questions.**

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this stuff to me!